# Configuring custom command for name and emails

Tags: macros

I like to configure and optimize the commands such that the same output of the following MWE obtains without using separate commands to insert the professor's name and email.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\profname}[1]{ \newcommand{\profnameloc}{#1} }
\newcommand{\profemail}[1]{ \newcommand{\profemailloc}{#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand\printprofemail{O{}O{}}{
            \texttt{\href{mailto:\profemailloc}{\profemailloc}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prof}{mO{}}{\newcommand\profloc{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\title{Custom Command}
\prof{Dr. X}[x@example.com]
\profname{Dr. X}
\profemail{x@example.com}

\maketitle

The course is taught by \profloc. His name is \profnameloc and his email is \printprofemail.

\end{document}
```

I mean, my desired input:

```
\documentclass{report}

% [necessary packages and commands]

\begin{document}

\title{Custom Command}
\prof{Dr. X}[x@example.com]

\maketitle

The course is taught by \profloc. His name is \profnameloc and his email is \profemailloc.

\end{document}
```

My desired output is like:

```
The course is taught by (Dr. X)[textbf and hyperlinked]. His name is Dr. X and his email is (x@example.com)[texttt and hyperlinked].
```

I want to use the professor email as an optional argument in the command `\prof` such that it should not generate a blank hyperlink if I just use the command `\prof{Dr. X}`. Also, I like to optimize the `\profmailloc` to print the same as `\printprofmail` of my MWE. I mean if the email is inserted like `\prof{Dr. X}[x@example.com]`, then `\profemailloc` should display the email address with hyperlink and if the email is not given, the `\profemailloc` should not print anything.

My desired output if `\prof{Dr. X}` is used instead of `\prof{Dr. X}[x@example.com]`:

```
The course is taught by (Dr. X)[textbf but not hyperlinked]. His name is Dr. X and his email is .
```

It should also be noted that my current MWE generates blank space issues after the commands, these should be fixed as well.

Comment: You've given your desired input, but the expected output isn't very clear. What should the output be? And in the case the optional argument to `\prof` hasn't been given?

Comment: I have updated the question for more clarity.